# Do I always have to use an object in English conversations?

Tags: sentence-construction, objects

I'm learning English without natives' help so it is kind of hard for me to confirm my English is grammatically correct or not.

One of my friend is from France and likes to point out my English mistake.

However, with all my heart, I do not like to accept it since both of us are not native English speakers.

Do I need to mention "an object" in every single sentence in a conversation?

For example:

> "do you like football?"
>
> "no~ not at all I dont like"
>
> "do you believe you teacher?"
>
> "nope I dont believe"

Of course if I write an essay, I will put an object every single time but in conversations, do I have to mention it every single time?

Comment: " do you like football?"

" no~ not at all I dont like [it]"

" do you believe your teacher?"

" nope I dont believe [him] " like this

Answer (score 8):

If you're asked a question with a *transitive verb* that takes an **object**:

> Do you *like* **football**?

you may safely convey your answer using something called "ellipsis," i.e., the omission of words that your reader or listener will supply from the context:

> No.
>   No, I don't.

But if you repeat the verb but omit the object

> No, I don't *like*.

it will sound odd to a native speaker, who will expect you to supply an object.  If you went to the trouble to say the verb, then perhaps you're about to say

> No, I don't *like* **to be argumentative**, but football bores me.

and your listener will be left hanging, wondering how and when you'll complete your thought.

Answer (score 0):

Objects help for clarity and make a sentence descriptive. A simple sentence (Clause) has a subject and a predicate (verb). Transitive verbs require a direct object but intransitive verbs do not, so it is possible and quite common to say things without an object.

English is more of an open than a closed language, and there are different kinds of grammar acceptable usage depending on the venue of conversation. There's formal grammar, which is mainly used w/the professional environment and in the court system. Another is informal grammar, which is used when your having a general conversation with someone out in public. The other to consider is friendly grammar, where you can make up terms that you and a group of friends understand and certain specifics aren't taken so seriously. You shorten a grammatically correct sentence simply because the listener ( your friend ) would understand it perfectly.

Comment: The examples the questioner gave are all shortened in such a way that a native speaker would expect an object.